# Angular - transferir componentes de um component pra outro

Tags: angular

Boa tarde. Tenho um component que contém alguns componentes filhos, tenho outro componente contendo outros componentes filhos. quero inverter os filhos de um pelo outro, mas quero que os filhos tragam consigo os seus eventos.

exemplo conceitual:

```html
<comp1>
  <compfilhoa [prop1]="vary"(event)="eventa($event)">
  </compfilhoa>

</comp1>

<comp2>
  <compfilhob [propr2]="varx" (event)="eventb($event)">
  </compfilhob>
</comp2>
```

Quero colocar em tempo de execução o compb dentro do comp1 e o compa dentro do comp2. quero que o compb e o compa levem todas as suas características e eventos.
Que biblioteca do Angular eu preciso usar pra fazer isso?

Comment: Parceiro, pra mim ficou um pouco embaralhado a idéia disto ai. Você poderia explicar em forma de regra de negócios? Trazendo mais para o mundo real pra que nós possamos assimilar melhor a idéia?

Comment: Os componentes `comp1` e `comp2` são os mesmos tipos? E os `compfilhoa` e `compfilhob` são os mesmos tipos? Se a resposta for sim pra ambos, já de antemão eu iria te sugerir trocar o objeto no seu .ts um com o outro, assim os componentes se atualizariam em tempo real com os novos dados.

Comment: então... eu estou fazendo o componente que seria o comp 1 e 2.. eu vou chamar de swap-drag-drop, a idéia é arrastar um sobre o outro e trocar o conteúdo. Eu não sei que componentes serão colocados dentro deles. Imagina que numa parte da tela tenha um swap-drag-drop com 3 botões e uma table e na outra parte eu tenho uma table totalmente diferente, ao arrastar um sobre o outro, inverterei os conteúdos. Eu fiz usando innerHTML, mas aí os métodos param de funcionar, se eu tiver um botão, ele não faz mais nada

Answer (score 0):

Se for o efeito [drag and drop](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c) o angular implementou na versão 7, pra transferir dados entre componentes você pode usar Input e output, ou Subject nos services para comunicação dos componentes, outra alternativa é usar alguma biblioteca para controlar o estado da aplicação, como [ngrx](https://ngrx.io)